# Flex mobile project for iOS doesn't work in release. Only in debug mode

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile

I have a mobile project for iOS and I can only see it working on debug mode in the iPad. When I run it on release, the screen remains blank.

The project has only some movieClips playing and not too much components. It's almost an animated presentation.

The crash report from the device says:

```
Application Specific Information:
com.testapp.game failed to resume in time
```

And later it says:

```
Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

And many other weird things.

What would be?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to load SWFs "on the fly"?  That won't work on iOS because it violates the developer terms of service about processing code at runtim3.  It may work in a debug version though [I'm not sure].

Comment: Actually I used all in swc. And the assets that I'm using does have some code, but they're created by new Asset(). Does it has something to do with that?

Comment: USing a SWC should have no affect in iOS.  I do not believe code w/in a MovieClip should have any problems either.  I'm not sure; hopefully someone else can chime in.